# Does Windows 10 search/indexing move files?

Tags: windows-10, search, windows-search, search-indexing

I was looking for a file in my `Downloads` folder (i.e. `C:\Users\QM\Downloads`) on my Win 10 Pro (build 1809) machine.  I was unable to find it there even though I was near certain that's where it was.

So I next typed the filename into the Search box.  It **did** show up there and I could open it, etc.

However, when (in the app) I selected *Show enclosing folder* it said the file was in `C:\Users\QM\Searches\Downloads`. So I went to that directory and the file was indeed there -- and so were a whole bunch of other files that I *know* were in my `Downloads` directory but aren't anymore.

So does Win 10 search or indexing actually *move* files?  If so, is there something special about `Downloads` or will it do that for other folders?  And is there any way to control this move files behavior?

(If it matters, I am not using Cortana.)

Comment: The `%user_profile%\searches` directory stores saved searches, as described here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/search/-search-savedsearchfileformat  Note however that if Downloads is a saved search, it is a virtual folder, so I believe the data it shows is actually the result of a query defined in the search saved as "Downloads". for instance I have one called "Indexed Locations", and when I open it, it appears to have every file on my system in it.  I note that it is possible to copy files to the Searches folder though. could have just been an accident.

Comment: There is definitely a separate, real `C:\Users\QM\Downloads` folder.  I just cut & pasted everything from `Searches\Downloads` into the real `Downloads` folder.  There were no duplicates, so it wasn't like `Searches\Downloads` was full of pointers or `C:\Users\QM\Downloads` was any sort of virtual thing.  I'll be keeping an eye on this and seeing if files move back out of the real `Downloads` into `Searches\Downloads`